# LLDB Python API call function in C code

Tags: python, gdb, lldb

For example, while writing GDB Macros, I can give something like:

```
list_iterate $arg0
```

If my list_iterate() function in the C code looks like

```
list_iterate(list_node *)
```

In the LLDB Python API, how do I do the same thing, i.e call and execute a function from the C code? I've scoured the documentation but can't seem to find something like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SBFrame::EvaluateExpression` is the function you want.  Something like:

```
(lldb) script
>>> options = lldb.SBExpressionOptions()
>>> result = lldb.frame.EvaluateExpression('printf("Hello there.\\n");', options)
Hello there.
>>> print result
(int) $1 = 13
```

Note, if you are writing scripts (or Python commands, etc.) don't use lldb.frame, you can get the selected frame from your process, or if you are writing a command use the form that gets passed an SBExecutionContext.  See:

https://lldb.llvm.org/use/python-reference.html

for more details.

Comment: Also wanted to ask one small thing. The result of my function is a pointer and I am able to execute your command successfully. result.GetValue() returns an address. However, when I run result.GetChildMemberWithName("data").GetValue() (My struct contains a member array int data[2]), I get None. But I've confirmed via the console that it is not None and has a value.

Is this a flaw with the code I've written or is there some issue in the result SBValue pointer?

Comment: GetChildMemberWithName is getting you an SBValue that represents the 2-element array "data".  Arrays don't have values - what would the value of an array mean?  Rather, they have children - the elements of the array.  So if you wanted to see data[0] you would get the SBValue for "data" using GetChildMemberWithName("data") and call GetChildAtIndex(0) on that.  The SBValue that gets returned from that call is a scalar, and will have a value.